# getting total number of records saved in django bulk_create

Tags: django, django-models

is there any way to get the number of total records inserted in Django model using `bulk_create`??

```
Entry.objects.bulk_create([
...     Entry(headline="Django 2.0 Released"),
...     Entry(headline="Django 2.1 Announced"),
...     Entry(headline="Breaking: Django is awesome")
... ])
```

In the above example, 3 records are inserted into the database.

How can I get the total number of records using `bulk_create`??

Comment: This is just the length of the list...

Comment: I've set `ignore_conflicts=True` in `bulk_create` to ignore rows that causes IntegrityError. (basically ignoring non-unique rows), I don't want the length of the list but the actual number of records inserted into database

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it would be to store the count before and subtract it after.

```
initial_count = Entry.objects.count()

Entry.objects.bulk_create([
...     Entry(headline="Django 2.0 Released"),
...     Entry(headline="Django 2.1 Announced"),
...     Entry(headline="Breaking: Django is awesome")
... ])

total_inserted = Entry.objects.count() - initial_count
```

Comment: This works but depending on the use-case/size of the table. Counts are very slow/expensive to get, so if latency is a concern this isn't ideal.